# Is there a way to automatically disable normal maps for mobile builds in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a Unity game for mobile, and I want to know if there is a way to remove normal maps from all materials (Standard shader, built in pipeline) when building for mobile platforms without removing them from other platforms. Using Unity 2021 LTS. I already looked through the Project Settings, and it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution to my own problem, so I'll post it here just in case anyone else needs it.

Create a file called NormalMapPreprocess.cs with this code, and put it in the Assets/Editor folder, and it will remove the normal maps at build time.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Rendering;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

#if UNITY_ANDROID
public class NormalMapPreprocess : IPreprocessShaders
{
    ShaderKeyword m_KeywordNormal;

    public NormalMapPreprocess()
    {
        m_KeywordNormal = new ShaderKeyword("_NORMALMAP");
    }

    public int callbackOrder { get { return 0; } }

    public void OnProcessShader(Shader shader, ShaderSnippetData snippet, IList<ShaderCompilerData> data)
    {
        for (int i = data.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (data[i].shaderKeywordSet.IsEnabled(m_KeywordNormal))
            {
                data.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
#else
public class NormalMapPreprocess {}
#endif
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can switch off Project Settings -> Graphics -> iOS/Android -> Tier N -> Detail Normal Map